# Merge jpgs to pdf Windows

Tags: powershell, jpeg, pdf-conversion

Hi I'm attempting to merge all jpgs in a directory into a pdf using a batch file. Currently I've been attempting to use PDFCreator, however I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use PDF Creator using cli. I've gone through the online manual and it doesn't really contain much for cli documentation from what I've seen most of the cli is for java anyway so it's not helpful to me.

When I attempt to save all jpgs as one pdf it outputs a blank pdf or does nothing at all. Currently I'm attempting this on one jpg in the directory as a proof of concept. Then once I have that working I'm going to attempt to take multiple jpgs and print them all into one pdf if that's possible with pdf-creator.

This is what I have.

```
## Multiple jpg to single PDF Conversion tool

$date = get-date -format MM-dd-yy_hhmmss
$InputLocation = "C:\conversion\"

$tool = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe'
$jpgs = gci $InputLocation\* -i '*.jpg', '*.jpeg' 

foreach($jpg in $jpgs)
{
    $filename = $jpg.FullName
    $pdf = $InputLocation + $date + '.pdf'

    'Processing ' + $filename  + ' to ' + $pdf      
    $param = "-sOutputFile=$pdf"
    Start-Process $tool -ArgumentList ('/IF"' + $filename + '" /OF"' + $pdf + ' /NoPSCheck /NoStart')
}

mkdir $InputLocation\$date
move $InputLocation\$date\$jpgs
```

Comment: Um, couldn't you just do `("/IF'$InputLocation*.jpg' /OF'$InputLocationOutput.pdf' /NoPSCheck /NoStart")` for your argument list?

Comment: Accoding to the documentation `/IF` will "_Convert a postscript file or a bitmap file (JPEG, BM) to a PDF or bitmap_" so i dont think he will be able to use a wildcard or support multiple files.

Comment: Better yet, if you are using PDF Creator why not use Images2PDF from the same creator? It gets installed along with PDF Creator by default and has a command line tool that will bulk convert images to a single PDF. It's as simple as: `Images2PDFC /i "D:\My Images\*.jpg" /e "D:\My PDFs\images.pdf"`

Comment: Thanks TheMadTechnician. You should make your comment into an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: You could generate a markdown file with all of the images then convert to PDF with pandoc